# Visual Basic to Excel Formula

Tags: vba, visual-studio, excel, excel-formula

My Visual Basic Codes are:

```
oExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "789"
oExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "123"
oExcel.Cells(2, 1).Formula = "=SUM(A1:B1)"
```

When I run my visual basic app, it opens excel worksheet but the formula doesn't work.  It will cause #NAME? error. But when i click the formula on formula bar on excel, then click somewhere else, the code strats to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
Sub TEst()
Excel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "789"
Excel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "123"
Excel.Cells(2, 1).Formula = "=SUM(A1:B1)"

End Sub
```

Hope it helps